# Turn device bluetooth on or off

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want my button in android studio to check whether the bluetooth is on or off from the same button and then turn it on or off accordingly from the source code, can anybody help me out here?

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you include some code samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to add these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

and to Enable/Disable Bluetooth programmatically use BluetoothAdapter
for example:

```
btnBluetooth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (adapter.isEnabled()){
                adapter.disable();
            } else {
                adapter.enable();
            }
} });
```

For more information check [Bluetooth Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Comment: How can i add it to the button that when clicked, will turn it on and off?

Comment: Yes, use the same code I showed in the example.

Comment: May I know plz, why location permission needed for this? I saw some other libraries also where they r using location permission for Bluetooth scanning. But not sure yet, why needed?

Comment: Location permission is often required for Bluetooth scanning and related functionality in mobile apps for several reasons:

**1** Bluetooth LE (Low Energy) Advertising                                  
**2** Proximity and Location-Based Services
**3** Background Scanning
**4** Operating System Requirements
**5** Privacy Concerns